# Debian Installer Preseed with Somewhat Dynamically Allocated Software RAID

Tags: linux, debian

I actually have two questions here regarding the `preseed.cfg` file.  One being how to calculate how much disk space to use for my scheme during the installation (for when I might be netbooting to install various sizes of hard disks).  The other being how to set up linux software RAID from the preseed.cfg file.

1. Rather than automatically using the whole disk, I would like to set it up to create 2GB MD device for use as `swap`, a 3GB MD device for use by ext3 at `/mnt/utility`, and all the rest of the disk space as the *first* partition, also an MD device for use as ext3 mounted at `/`.  Is there a way to specify sizes for some partitions and then allocate "everything else" to one partition?
2. I'm having a hard time finding linux RAID examples for debian's preseed.cfg--in fact I have no idea what that would look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't that what you are looking for? https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/installation-guide/amd64/preseed-contents.html

There are examples for RAID and examples for fixed, percentual and "all-the-rest" disk sizes.

And Ubuntu is Debian, so all parameters should be usable on Debian, too.